# Find IP from CIDR

Tags: python

I am searching for IPs listed in `s1` in CIDR listed in `s2`. So basically, I want to expand all elements of `s2` and search for IPs. Not sure how to get IPs from `s1`, if use `re.compile`. I am not getting ip4:, how do I remove the ip4: part

```
import re

s1 = ["ip4:64.18.10.101", "ip4:66.102.10.10", "spf1", "mx"]
s2 = "v=spf1 ip4:64.18.0.0/20 ip4:66.102.0.0/20 ~all"

list = s2.split(' ')
regex = re.compile("ip.*")
for ip in list:
    if re.search(regex, ip):
        print ip
```

Comment: What's the problem of your code and what's your desired output?

Comment: `regex = re.compile("ip.*")                                                                           for ip in list:
    from netaddr import IPNetwork
    print ip
    for ip_cidr in IPNetwork('72.14.192.0/18'):
        if ip_cidr == ip:
            print "pass"`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I wrote this:

```
#/usr/bin/python
import os
import re
from netaddr import IPNetwork
import subprocess
import shlex

cmd = '/usr/bin/dig +short -t TXT _netblocks.google.com'
proc=subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd),stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
s1,err=proc.communicate()

cmd3 = '/usr/bin/dig +short -t TXT _netblocks3.google.com'
proc=subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd3),stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
s3,err=proc.communicate()

s2 = ''.join([s1,s3])
regex = re.compile("\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\/[0-9][0-9]")
list = re.findall(regex, s2)
f2 = open("s1.txt", "w")
for ip in list:
    for ip1 in IPNetwork(ip):
        #print ip1
        f2.write(str(ip1)+'\n')


#######################
f = open("/var/log/iptables.log")
f1 = open("s_out.txt", "w")
pattern = re.compile(r"\bSRC\=\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+")
for line in f:
    test = re.findall(pattern,line)
    for line in test:
        line1 = re.split("=", line)
        f1.write(line1[1]+'\n')
f1.close()


#######################
with open('s_out.txt', 'r')as f1:
    with open('s1.txt', 'r') as f2:
        same = set(f1).intersection(f2)
same.discard('\n')

with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in same:
        file_out.write(line)

uniqlines = set(open('outfile.txt').readlines())
bar = open('output_file.txt', 'w').writelines(set(uniqlines))
```